# Excel: How to sort duplicate cells by ignoring full stops at the end of the strings?

Tags: excel

I have got strings in column A. Now I need to sort the duplicate strings.
Problem here is, for a few strings "." full stop is there at the end of the strings and a few doesn't. But the strings are similar. I want to ignore the full stop at the end and compare and sort the duplicates.

Ex:
[image: excel image]

Comment: Have you tried anything...?

Comment: The only solution I could find is , use IF condition to check if there is "." at the end and if yes ignore and if no add a "."  and copy to new columns and then compare. Which is a tedious process and  dumb.

Answer (score 0):

=Replace(A2, ".","")

Use this formula in B2 and do conditional formatting on the B column

Comment: that way I will have "." at the end of every string.

Comment: I think you meant to use SUBSTITUTE; that is not the correct syntax for REPLACE.

Comment: Sorry my bad. using this =Replace(A2, ".","") will remove all "." 's.